# How to I calculate a "maximum mask" for a 2d array with numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am trying to find the mask for the maximum value in every 2x2 block in a 2d array (for max pooling backpropagation in a CNN).

**Example**

```
[[ 0  1  4  0]
 [ 4  2  3  3]
 [ 2  0  3  2]
 [ 0  1  5  1]]
```

Needs to become:

```
[[ 0  0  1  0]
 [ 1  0  0  0]
 [ 1  0  0  0]
 [ 0  0  1  0]]
```

The 2x2 block on the top left of the first array is 0 1, 4 2. The max is 4 so it is replaced by a 1, and the non-max values are all replaced by 0. This is done for every 2x2 block with no overlap.

**Attempt:**

I've tried using `np.argmax` but I can only use one integer for the axis parameter, unlike `np.max`. I have also tried to think of a way to do this with indices, but I am in no way a professional when it comes to numpy so I did not get very far.

Any help or suggestion is well appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use `skimage`:

```
>>> from skimage.util import view_as_blocks
>>> a = np.array([[0,1,4,0],[4,2,3,3],[2,0,3,2],[0,1,5,1]])
>>> ab = view_as_blocks(a, (2, 2))
>>> abm = np.max(ab, axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True) == ab
>>> abm.astype(np.int32).reshape(a.shape)
array([[0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]], dtype=int32)
```

Note that if in a (2, 2) block there are two (or more) elements equal to the maximum in that block, they all get marked as 1.

Comment: Just asking out of curiosity (because such a method would be dangerous), could you confirm, if `ab[:] = (np.max(ab, axis=(2, 3), keepdims=True) == ab)` modifies the array `a` inplace?

Comment: @SayandipDutta I don't think so but don't quote me on that.

Comment: I see, I was thinking, as the name suggests, `view_as_blocks`, most probably it uses `np.lib.stride_tricks.as_strided` internally, if so, it returns a view, which would imply assigning via `slices` should modify `a`. Nonetheless, will try later, and if you get time and find this out, please let me know.

Comment: One problem with your posted solution that I did not notice earlier, is that it only works on a 4x4 input matrix. This is partly my fault because I never mentioned I needed it to work for other even-sized arrays, so sorry about that. The only part that doesn't work is the very last command ".reshape(a.shape)". Thanks